# How can Extract Class Eclipse IDE refactoring functionality be useful?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I came across a refactoring functionality that looks to be useful as I learn eclipse and java. But I'm not sure how this could be useful. Is there a pattern that would benefit from this kind of refactoring? This refactoring option basically extracted out all variables into another class whose name was changed to append `Data` at the end.

Any examples of WHAT/WHY this kind of refactoring gives us would be really helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Extract Class is mostly used when a class has too many responsibilities; it is trying to do too much. It splits out the class into two individual classes and then transfers some functionality into the other class - obviously there will be a relationship between the classes because you still want all of the code to interact.

You can combine Extract Class with other refactoring patterns such as Move Method and Move Field that will move methods and fields to the other class in such a way that all of the code still works as intended.

This link has a good example of Extract Class: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-class

Answer (score 0):

If you had too many fields in your class and you see that this must be a extra class, you can use it.

Example:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private int streetnumber; 
}
```

to:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private Adress data = new Adress(); 
}

public class Address {
    public String street;
    public int streetnumber;

    public Address() {}
}
```